# Capturing file changes with Google Drive SDK

Tags: google-apps, google-drive-api

Honest to say, I haven't been able to deeply look inside the Google Drive API so far but I wonder if the API has support for what I need. I would like to capture changes under a specific folder and notify the users which has access to that folder.

For example, I have a folder named **Foo** and there are three people who have access to that folder. When **Person 1** makes a notable change (uploads a file, changes a file, deletes a file, etc) under that folder, I would like to notify the **Person 2** and **Person 3**.

> Please note here that these changes can be done from anywhere, not just
>   from my client. The person can take the action through the Google Drive web
>   interface or the user might be syncing his/her computer with the
>   Google Drive.

The only part I cannot visualize in my head is how to capture the changes under a specific folder.

For the record, I will be using .NET for my client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [changes feed](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/changes/list) in our just-launched Drive SDK v2.  However, the changes feed does not yet support retrieving changes for just a specific folder.  Instead, it gives all changes to a user's entire Drive.  This is a feature request that we're considering implementing, but I don't have a timeline as to when we'll implement this yet.

Comment: Has the feature to watch a specific folder been implemented yet?