# Tracking changes on a file on Google Drive SDK

Tags: .net, google-drive-api

I want to show the user in my app recent activity on a file (same as on drive site - when user click on file info I wanna show him for example that today I change title of the file from "XYZ" to "ABC"). I use Google Drive SDK for .NET (latest v1.9.2.1930). I found that I should use ChangesResource https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-changes and in test I'm getting good results, but... I don't see any way to get all changes for specific file, accodring to this this feature should be implemented now: [Capturing file changes with Google Drive SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11230346/capturing-file-changes-with-google-drive-sdk) but I don't see it. Obviously I can't download all the changes and look for ones that interest me on the client side - it would take forever. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [Files Watch](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/watch) api that allows you to watch for changes on a specific file.

Comment: It looks to me that I must have some kind of webService to use this, but I don't need to be notify 'live' - I just need to download changes for specific file when user clicks on it

Comment: I see, in that case I would try with the [Revisions API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/revisions) to get all the changes made, but I'm not sure how to get sharing changes.